# Why won't GRUB see any partitions other than Boot? Can't mount an ISO image and menuentry doesn't work

Tags: grub2

Ubuntu Release 20.04.1 LTS

```
sudo grub-install -V
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.7
```

From the `grub > ls` will display drives but only the contents of the boot partition. No other partitions are recognized.
Needless to say, my menu entries for the /etc/grub.d/40_custom files go Nowhere.

This worked before in Ubuntu Release 18.04 I'm trying to get back there as the application I need to run is not supported by this release. Can I install the older GRUB version?

Comment: Are they not partitions, but LVM volumes or RAID? Then you may need extra drivers, grub uses .mod files and you use insmod to load them. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: /dev/sdb1: UUID="e060c057-a000-46ba-9912-6d803669dc52" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="28f89cf4-01"
This was the partition I had the iso file on, that GRUB2 couldn't access from the grub terminal.

Comment: This server was hosted within a esx-i environment and we were able to use an iso file locally to get the older version of ubuntu installed. GRUB2 was able to access this partition in version 18.04 from the GRUB terminal and I was able to add the custom entry to the GRUB menu and boot from that iso. Not so with 20.04 it seems. Thank you though.

Comment: I boot 20.04 with grub. But some systems need this line added `rmmod tpm` Some others it gives me an error on that line & I have to bypass it.